# High-level Matlab functions to Python

Tags: python, numpy, matlab

I'm sorry to ask this (I know it's not a fair question but I can't ask anyone else):

```
function [w,f,stima,epoca]=eq10(aa,lr,w,p,npatt,ncomp,funz,x,alpha,intsup,maxit)
%Robust GHA algorithm (hierarchic) 

testnorm=1.0;
epoca=0;


w = w / norm(w);
wold=w;


while(testnorm>0.0001 && epoca<maxit)
   k=0;
   xup=[];
     
   while(k<=npatt)
      
      xup(1:ncomp,1)=aa(1+k:ncomp+k).'; 
      if (funz==1)
         gy=tanh(alpha.*xup.'*w);
      else
         gy=sign(xup.'*w).*log(1+abs(alpha*xup.'*w));
      end
      
      w=w+lr.*(xup*gy-w*triu((xup.'*w).'*gy));
        w = w / norm(w);
      
      k=k+1;
   end
   
   w = real((w*w.')^(-.5) *w);
       
   [flagtot,f,stima]=visfrStima(w,ncomp,npatt,p,x,intsup);
   
   testnorm=0.0;
   
   for index = 1 : p
      testnorm = testnorm  + sqrt(sum((wold(:,index)-w(:,index)).^2));   
   end
   disp(['Epoca:' num2str(epoca) ' ' 'Testnorm: ' num2str(testnorm)]);
   wold = w;   
  
   epoca=epoca+1;
end
```

This is the matlab function I have to translate in python.

The last step I translated is this:

```
gy=tanh(alpha.*xup.'*w);
```

I don't even know how to visualize this: I tried in matlab and it seems a 2-components array. I tried to visualized it with this, but it doesnt work:

```
for k in range (0, len(GY), 1):
     print("TanH[%d] = %f" %(k, GY[k]))
```

This is the error message:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

The function itself seems to work, I mean, I don't get any error when I run the program, but since I can't visualize it, I don't know if I did a good job.

This is my translation:

```
GY = np.tanh(np.multiply(np.multiply(Alpha, XUp), WSeg))
```

if you were asking, WSeg = W

I'd like to know how to correct the visualization function and ... well, it's not easy to ask, but ... I'd like a little help with the rest of the code, at least knowing what should I do.

I0ve never used Matlab in the last 5 years, and even when I used it, it was never stuff this complicated.

Comment: In Matlab, `*` is matrix multiplication, `.*` is element-wise multiplication and `.'` is transpose ([MATLAB Operators and Special Characters](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/matlab-operators-and-special-characters.html)). For Numpy, `@` is matrix multiplication, `*` is element-wise multiplication and `.T` is transpose. Thus you can translate it as follows: `gy = tanh(alpha * xup.T @ w)` (or `gy = tanh((alpha * xup).T @ w)` depending on operator precedence in Matlab, which I'm not sure about).

Comment: Hi, thank you. Can you tell me how to print GY ? I tried printing it as a variable and as an Array, but none of that worked. Is it a matrix ? Could be ? It should be a 2-element vector (in matlab it's shown as such).

Comment: It is a multi-dimensional array, you can check its shape via `print(gy.shape)`. When you print `gy` directly, it will probably not show all elements if it's too big. You can also plot it via `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.imshow(gy); plt.show()`.